# Compare time in string and subtract 10 min from that in iphone?

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have Array of time string like "10:10:12","12:10:34","05:23:11" this. I want to calculate less(min) time form that array i.e "05:23:11" and subtract 10 min from that. And save result in same format. Please if any one knows how to do it help me. I will appreciate to him/her. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array with dates is big u can do it llike this:

```
    NSArray * arrayWithTime = [NSArray array];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

 NSSortDescriptor *d = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1,id obj2){ 


NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj1];
NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj2];

return [date1 compare:date2];} ];

NSArray * comparators = [NSArray arrayWithObject:d];
NSArray * final = [arrayWithTime sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:comparators];
```

then just take the first item in final array and subtract 10 min

Comment: It works for me. I took 1st element and then use aopsfan logic for minus 10 min form that time element. Thanks to all.

Comment: @python my solution is much cleaner than this because it does all this in one line.  You don't really need a sort descriptor, let `@selector(compare:)` to that work for you.

Answer (score 2):

First, order the strings in ascending order.  If your array of strings is called `arrayOfTimeStrings`, then you can get a correctly-ordered array like so:

```
NSArray *array = [arrayOfTimeStrings sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Next, just grab the first item:

```
NSString *firstTimeString = (NSString *)[array objectAtIndex:0];
```

Now, you can convert that to an `NSDate` like so:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateFromFirstString = [formatter dateFromString:firstTimeString];
```

Finally, we can subtract 600 seconds from that date and convert it back to an `NSString`:

```
NSDate *tenMinutesBeforeDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-600 sinceDate:dateFromFirstString];
NSString *tenMinutesBeforeString = [formatter stringFromDate:tenMinutesBeforeDate];
```

This would be much simpler than the other solution because you won't have to come up with your own sorting algorithm.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, the first thing that comes to my mind is this:

```
NSString *strDate1 = @"10:10:12";
NSString *strDate2 = @"05:23:11";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate1];
NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate2];

//to compare dates
if([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending)
{
    //do what you want
}

//to subtract 10 min form a date
NSDate *date3 = [date2 dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*10];
```

I hope it helps.